# Playing with Rust's tuples

Tags: tuples, rust, unsigned-integer

Here's the link where was playing with Rust:

http://rustbyexample.com/match/guard.html

I found Rust showing warnings for the case when i negate an unsigned variable, so executing code below ends with

> warning: negation of unsigned int variable may be unintentional

Code:

```
fn main() {
let some = 2953495866u;
let pair = (some, -some);
// TODO ^ Try different values for `pair`

println!("Tell me about {}", pair);
// Match can be used to destructure a tuple
match pair {
    // Destructure the tuple
    (x, y) if x == y => println!("These are twins"),
    // The ^ `if condition` part is a guard
    (x, y) if x + y == 0 => println!("Antimatter, kaboom!"),
    // `_` means don't bind the value to a variable
    (x, _) if x % 2 == 1 => println!("The first one is odd"),
    _ => println!("No correlation..."),
}
}
```

But when you change the code into somewhat like

```
let pair = (2953495866u, -2953495866);
```

it runs silently ending up with tuple of (2953495866, 18446744070756055750) what is 2 unsigned integers. As for me, i'd rather expect warning here about casting negative number into uint.

What do you think about this situation?

Comment: This is not suited for StackOverflow, as you ask for our opinion. Talk to us on IRC (mozilla/#rust), Reddit, or file an Issue if you think this shall be changed. Ontopic: `echo 'fn main() {let pair = (2953495866u, -2953495866);}' | rustc -` warns me about ` cannot determine a type for this local variable: cannot determine the type of this integer; add a suffix to specify the type explicitly [E0102]`...

Answer (score 2):

An explanation, just in case. In this code:

```
fn main() {
    //let some = 2953495866u;
    let pair = (2953495866u, -2953495866);
    // TODO ^ Try different values for `pair`

    println!("Tell me about {}", pair);
    // Match can be used to destructure a tuple
    match pair {
        // Destructure the tuple
        (x, y) if x == y => println!("These are twins"),
        // The ^ `if condition` part is a guard
        (x, y) if x + y == 0 => println!("Antimatter, kaboom!"),
        // `_` means don't bind the value to a variable
        (x, _) if x % 2 == 1 => println!("The first one is odd"),
        _ => println!("No correlation..."),
    }
}
```

`-2953495866` literal is untyped; it means that the type checker can deduce its concrete type from its usage. It turns out that it is stored into a tuple and then this tuple is destructured and its two components are compared. Because the first component type is `uint` (because the corresponding literal has `u` suffix), the type checker decides that the second component type is also `uint`, hence that literal should be `uint` as well.

That the lint about negation of unsigned value is not fired does seem like a bug in the compiler. I've submitted it [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16445).